# How to build a static library from two directories?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have two folders with two different libraries.

- LibBase
- LibPublic

LibB includes some LibBase's headers.

I'd like to have LibPublic as a static library including "LibBase" in its `.a` file.

- Each CMakeLists.txt is:

```
set(SRCLIB file.cpp)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRCLIB})
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}::${PROJECT_NAME} ALIAS ${PROJECT_NAME})
target_include_directories(...)
```

- The top level CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory(LibBase)
add_subdirectory(LibPublic)
```

How can I force CMake to include LibBase inside LibPublic so that I can only share `libLibPublic.a`?

`LibBase` is a proprietary library and `LibPublic` is the "public" library we share.

LibBase and LibPublic, both may be added using `add_subdirectory()` by other libraries or apps so that a single app executable or a single .a file can be provided. Each "library" should be compiled as just objects, static library or even dynamic library. I'd like them to be generic, and an upper CMakeLists.txt will decide what to do.

I tried with `add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}-obj OBJECT ${SRCLIB})` but I get errors:

```
CMakeLists.txt:22 (target_include_directories):
  Cannot specify include directories for target "LibPublic" which is not
  built by this project.
```

Comment: I think you are conflating [CMake Object libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) with static libraries.

Comment: I don't really understand it. I don't understand why I can't find the right answer to my simple use case... Why CMake makes things so complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Given the following file and some dummy cpp files:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(foo)

add_library(Base STATIC base.cpp)
add_library(Public STATIC public.cpp)
target_sources(Public PRIVATE $<TARGET_OBJECTS:Base>)
```

I end up with a `libPublic.a` that contains functions from both libraries.

Note that this is a solution to your question, but maybe not a solution to your underlying requirement: static libraries are simple collections of functions and the functions in "Base" are plainly visible.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is they are in two different folders. And are more or less independent. CMakeLists.txt of other libraries or apps may `add_subdirectory()` them.

Comment: If libpublic is to contain libbase, it is not independent by definition.

Comment: I mean, both "libraries" may be linked as static libraries but also, some apps want them as source without linking them as libraries. (so that the app is provided without extra .a files)

Comment: These are important constraints and should be part of your question.

Comment: I edited, I really feel like the solution is in CMake's "object library" but can't find how. Am I wrong?

Comment: looks like this answer my question: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/tutorials/Object-Library I just need to try

Comment: As my answer already shows, you can get the same functionality by using the `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:tgt>` generator expression on a static library

Comment: I'll try, thanks. I'll come back to accept the answer.

Comment: Regarding your earlier comment: the `target_sources` line can live at the top level; it does not have to go with either one of the libraries.